# Instagram stories php cURL 5xx Server Error

Tags: php, curl, instagram, instagram-api

I'm trying to access Instagram Stories endpoint as described [here](https://medium.com/@calialec/chrome-ig-story-bribing-the-instagram-story-api-with-cookies-c813e6dff911) and [here](https://github.com/jlobos/instagram-stories/blob/master/index.js) but with PHP -- sending user_id and sessionid obtained with Spy HTTP Chrome Extension.

I'm getting the response/error: **string(105) "5xx Server Error"**
¿What it could be?

Also when i change the user agent to `Instagram 10.8.0 Android (18/4.3; 320dpi; 720x1280; Xiaomi; HM 1SW; armani; qcom; en_US` i get **string(67) "{"message": "login_required", "logout_reason": 2, "status": "fail"}**"

```
function Geturl($url){
    $process = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "ds_user_id=XXXXXX; sessionid=XXXXXX");
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Instagram 9.5.1 (iPhone9,2; iOS 10_0_2; en_US; en-US; scale=2.61; 1080x1920) AppleWebKit/420+");
    $return = curl_exec($process); 
    if(curl_error($process))
    {
        return 'error:' . curl_error($process);
    }
    curl_close($process); 

    return $return;
}

var_dump(Geturl("https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/feed/reels_tray/"));
```

Answer (score 1):

The URL endpoint was wrong, the working URL is:

```
var_dump(Geturl("http://i.instagram.com/api/v1/feed/user/user-id/reel_media/"));
```